# haystack is unable to connect to solr search engine

Tags: python, django, solr, django-haystack

solr search engine is running at 'http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr' and my django-haystack setting are

```
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.solr_backend.SolrEngine',
    'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr',
    # ...or for multicore...
    # 'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/mysite',
    'TIMEOUT': 60 * 5,
},
```

}

I created schema.xml file of django app with command `python manage.py build_solr_schema > schema.xml`

and placed it in `solr-4.10.4\example\solr\collection1\conf` directory and restarted the solr search engine with `java -jar start.jar` and it restarts with no exceptions or error. 
when I am rebuilding the index file `python manage.py rebuild_index` for the newly copied schema it shows the following error

> "Removing all documents from your index because you said so.
>   Failed to clear Solr index: [Reason: None]
>   504 Gateway Timeout
>
> ## Gateway Timeout
>
> Server error - server 127.0.0.1 is unreachable at this moment.
> Please retry the request or contact your adminstrator.
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):"

I get the same error when  solr search engine is not running hence I am assuming that the error is because the django-haystack is not able to connect solr search engine although I made sure that is running at the aforementioned ip address. there are no proxies involved. I am using solr version 4.10.2. with the similar settings I was able to connect django haystack with solr server from another windows desktop. please help, I am struggling with this issue from two days.

Comment: Can you telnet to 127.0.0.1:8983 from the same command line you are running python and see if you get a connection? If yes, then python is trying to do something wrong (system level proxy?). If not, then your Solr is misbehaving for whatever reason.

Comment: @AlexandreRafalovitch thanks for the suggestion. I did telnet from the dir I am running python  **Connecting To http://127.0.0.1:8983...Could not open connection to the host, on port 23: Connect failed**  and you are right the solr server is not reachable. However what is strange is I am able   to access the server from chrome browser but  in mozilla browser it says **Server error - server 127.0.0.1 is unreachable at this moment.**, I don't know what the issue could be, it is strange.

Comment: sorry, it is *telnet 127.0.0.1 8983* with the space for the port. It should tell you "connecting to port 23". Still, check your browser configurations. Maybe there is a misconfigured proxy somewhere. Also try using *localhost* instead of 127.0.0.1. Should be identical but something is obviously wrong.

Comment: @AlexandreRafalovitch I am able to telnet 127.0.0.1 8983 and localhost 8983 but not http://127.0.0.1 8983 and http://localhost 8983 . `HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.solr_backend.SolrEngine',
         'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr',
        #'URL': 'http://localhost:8983/solr',
        # ...or for multicore...
        # 'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/mysite',
        'TIMEOUT': 60 * 5,
    },
}` removing http:// from haystack connection is giving error 'no connection adapter was found' the configuration works from another desktop.

Comment: I figured out that the problem firefox was because of proxy, I removed the proxy and the url http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/#/ in firefox. I removed the proxy from system using `netsh winhttp reset proxy` from cmd but still I get the same error.., I tried almost everything I know...:(

Comment: Can you connect to the **same** Solr from the other machine? If yes, you definitely have something wrong on this machine. I would try just running a Vanilla server on a different machine and see if you can connect to that. And you definitely don't need collection name in the URL? I don't know haystack that well.

Comment: @AlexandreRafalovitch thanks alot, the problem is with the machine, i will try to set another server